# How to change key-value in dictionary using dictionary comprehension + if/else?

Tags: python, dictionary, derivative, polynomials

I'm given a dictionary with exponents-coefficients as key-value pairs for polynomials. My task is to make a function to return a dictionary containing the derivative exponents-coefficients key-value pairs. This is what I have got so far, but it is not working:

```
def diff_p(d):
    d = {i - 1: i*d[i] if i is not 0 else d[i]: 0 for i in d}
    return d

p = {0: -3, 3: 2, 5: -1}
```

Why do I get syntax error? And can someone come up with a good remedy, preferably a one liner?

Update:

Thanks to Karl Knechtel's answer one can make this task into this neat one liner:

`deff_p = lambda d: {e - 1: c*e for e, c in d.items() if e != 0}`

Comment: What is the `else` clause supposed to mean? `else` 0?

Comment: If the exponent (d[i])  is 0 (x^0 = 1) which means d[i] is a constant, then its derivative is 0, hence d[i]  : 0

Comment: Do you mean, if `i` isn't 0, then `d = {i - 1: i*d[i]}`. Otherwise, `d = {d[i]: 0}`? However, in this case, let's say `i` is 0. Python thinks you mean: `d = {i - 1: d[i]: 0 for i in d}` since your `if..else` works at: `i*d[i] if i is not 0 else d[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i - 1: i*d[i] if i is not 0 else d[i]: 0
```

The problem is that you are thinking of `i - 1: i*d[i]` and `d[i]: 0` as single "terms" in the expression. They are not. You need to use separate conditional logic for both the key and the value.

Also, you should use `==` and `!=` for numeric comparison, not `is` and `is not`.

So that would give you `{(i - 1 if i != 0 else d[i]): (i*d[i] if i != 0 else 0) for i in d}`. (It should work without the parentheses, but I think it's really hard to read that way.)

That said, given that your dictionary represents the coefficients of a polynomial, and the function performs differentiation, I can't understand why you're putting in this weird special-cased term. Constant terms of polynomials are supposed to disappear entirely when you differentiate; the natural logic is therefore to filter that out entirely, like: `{i - 1: i*d[i] for i in d if i != 0}`.

Finally, typically it's considered cleaner to iterate over the key-value pairs ("items") of the dictionary directly: `{e - 1: c * e for e, c in d.items() if e != 0}` (here I have written `e` for "exponent" and `c` for "coefficient").

Comment: Thanks alot, that was really useful information and cleared things up, also the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def diff_p(d):
    d = {i-1: i*d[i] for i in d if i != 0}
    return d
```

This simply removes the constant term (i.e. zero exponent), since its derivative is zero.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i'm looking for, come to think of it. I don't need the 0 key for the derivative:)